# How do I control the timeout for a webservice call in WinDev?

Tags: web-services, windev

We have integrated with several different 3rd party web services but we have seen long waits and even timeouts from these services.  Is there a way to set the amount of time to wait?

Comment: The HTTPTimeOut() does not reference the SOAPRunXML() command as being affected... seems like it would.

Answer (score 2):

As you already noted HTTPTimeOut works for most network connections. So in my experience it also works for SOAPRunXML().

http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3043008 HTTPTimeOut

http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3069014 SOAPRunXML

In HTTPTimeOut is a reference to SOAPRun but in soap run there is no reference to HTTPTimeOut. This shows that the documentation is far from complete.

Comment: Based on our testing, HTTPTimeOut does seem to work!